# How to modify a component's value within a redeclare statement via OMPython

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica

I need to be able to modify the contents of a Modelica package/model via Python, for automated simulation etc. Mostly this works fine with OMPython, but there is a special problem I cannot solve:

Consider these two files:
1) example.mo (A Modelica package)

```
package Example "Example Package"
  model Component "A component with some settings"
    parameter Real value=100 "Some value";
    replaceable BasicSensor sensor "Replaceable sensor" annotation (
        Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})),
        __Dymola_choicesAllMatching=true);
    annotation (Icon(graphics={Rectangle(extent={{-40,40},{40,-40}}, lineColor={28,
                108,200})}));
  end Component;

  model System "A system with a component"
    Component component(value=50, redeclare SpecialSensor sensor(sensitivity=10))
      "Modified component"
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(
          coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
  end System;

  model BasicSensor
    parameter Real sensitivity=1 "Some value";
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false), graphics={
            Ellipse(extent={{-40,40},{40,-40}}, lineColor={28,108,200})}),
        Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
  end BasicSensor;

  model SpecialSensor
    extends BasicSensor;
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(
          coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
  end SpecialSensor;
end Example;
```

2) test.py (A Python script)

```
"""Python test script for replacing information in modelica models."""
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
cmds = [
    'loadFile("example.mo")',
    'setComponentModifierValue(Example.System, component.value, $Code(=200))',
    # 'setComponentModifierValue(Example.System, component.sensor.sensitivity, $Code(=20))',
    'saveModel("example_edit.mo", Example)',
    ]
for cmd in cmds:
    answer = omc.sendExpression(cmd)
    print(cmd, answer)
```

In Modelica, we have a "System" that contains a "Component" which in turn contains a replaceable "sensor".
With the Python script I can properly modify "component.value". Running the script yields the following result file example_edit.mo (only showing the part with changes):

```
model System "A system with a component"
    Component component(value = 200, redeclare SpecialSensor sensor(sensitivity = 10)) "Modified component" annotation(
      Placement(transformation(extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
    annotation(
      Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)),
      Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)));
  end System;
```

"component.value" has been changed from 50 to 200, as desired.

However, I do not know how to change the "sensitivity" of the redeclared sensor. The naive approach is the commented line in the python script. If we include that line, the replaced sensor simply vanishes from the resulting model

```
model System "A system with a component"
    Component component(value = 200) "Modified component" annotation(
      Placement(transformation(extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
    annotation(
      Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)),
      Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)));
  end System;
```

Finally, the actual question: 
**How can I achieve the following desired result with the "sensitivity" changed to 20?** (Through the OMPython interface, not with with regex or similar hacks.)

```
model System "A system with a component"
    Component component(value = 200, redeclare SpecialSensor sensor(sensitivity = 20)) "Modified component" annotation(
      Placement(transformation(extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
    annotation(
      Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)),
      Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)));
  end System;
```

Regards and many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With feedback from openmodelica.org I realized that OpenModelica currently (1.14.1) does not fully support those redeclare statements. Thus the desired result is plainly not possible yet. It seems to be planned for 1.16.0.

See a [question on openmodelica.org](https://www.openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/3011-how-to-modify-a-component-s-value-within-a-redeclare-statement-via-cli) and the [roadmap](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/roadmap) for future reference. Also this might be the correct [ticket to track](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2079).

Edit:

With the current dev build of OpenModelica v1.17.0-dev-326-g94acb25482 (64-bit), the following Python code allows setting redeclare statements and answers the original question:

```py
"""Python test script for replacing information in modelica models."""
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
cmds = [
    'loadFile("example.mo")',   
    'removeElementModifiers(Example.System, "component", false)',
    'setElementModifierValue(Example.System, component.sensor, $Code((redeclare SpecialSensor sensor(sensitivity = 20))))',
    'setElementModifierValue(Example.System, component.value, $Code(=200))',
    'saveModel("example_edit.mo", Example)',
    ]
for cmd in cmds:
    answer = omc.sendExpression(cmd)
    print(cmd, ':', answer)
```

This creates the desired output:

```
  model System "A system with a component"
    Component component(value = 200, redeclare SpecialSensor sensor(sensitivity = 20)) "Modified component" annotation(
      Placement(transformation(extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
    annotation(
      Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)),
      Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)));
  end System;
```

However, it seems like the command `removeElementModifiers()` is currently required, because without it...

```py
"""Python test script for replacing information in modelica models."""
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
cmds = [
    'loadFile("example.mo")',   
    # 'removeElementModifiers(Example.System, "component", false)',
    'setElementModifierValue(Example.System, component.sensor, $Code((redeclare SpecialSensor sensor(sensitivity = 20))))',
    'setElementModifierValue(Example.System, component.value, $Code(=200))',
    'saveModel("example_edit.mo", Example)',
    ]
for cmd in cmds:
    answer = omc.sendExpression(cmd)
    print(cmd, ':', answer)
```

... the `redeclare SpecialSensor` part is missing in the output:

```
  model System "A system with a component"
    Component component(value = 200) "Modified component" annotation(
      Placement(transformation(extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
    annotation(
      Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)),
      Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false)));
  end System;
```

Comment: Just a quick note: the redeclares are supported if you want to compile the model. What we we are talking here is about the API to get/set the information about redeclares in the Modelica code via scripts or from OMEdit.

Comment: @AdrianPop I don't know if you will read this, but is there a way to use ``setElementModifierValue()`` with redeclare code without first using ``removeElementModifiers()``? Maybe I am still missing something... first reading all existing values, saving them, and then reapplying them is quite tedious, when all I want to do is change a single value.

Comment: If you don't remove anything and call setElementModifierValue I think it should update it.

Comment: @AdrianPop Thanks for getting back to me, much appreciated.I expanded my answer to show the output when I don't use ``removeElementModifiers()``: The redeclare part is missing. The order of setting component.sensor and component.value also does not matter in that case, only ``value`` survives the process. Is this unintended behaviour? Should I create an issue on GitHub?

Comment: I created an issue here: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/7182